# What should the type of parameter be in Java when it is a "timestamp without time zone" in postgresql?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to run a query in postgresql through Java and JDBC.

The "activitydate" column of "table" in postgresql is "timestamp without time zone". I tried to use String to pass the date but didn't work(**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone > character varying)**.

What type instead of **String** should I use to store "start_date" and "end_date" and pass them to the query?

BTW `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE activitydate > '2014-11-20' AND activitydate < '2014-11-21' AND zipcode = 12345` runs perfectly in pgadmin.

```
public Response query(
          @QueryParam("start_date") String start_date,
          @QueryParam("end_date") String end_date,
          @QueryParam("zipcode") String zipcode
          ) throws Exception {
...
...

pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE activitydate > ? AND activitydate < ? AND zipcode = ?");

pstmt.setString(1, start_date); 
pstmt.setString(2, end_date); 
pstmt.setString(3, zipcode);
```

Update:
I changed it to java.sql.Timestamp but still doesn't work:

```
public Response query(
          @QueryParam("start_date") Timestamp start_date,
          @QueryParam("end_date") Timestamp end_date,
          @QueryParam("zipcode") String zipcode
          ) throws Exception {
...
...

pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE activitydate > ? AND activitydate < ? AND zipcode = ?");

pstmt.setTimestamp(1, start_date); 
pstmt.setTimestamp(2, end_date); 
pstmt.setString(3, zipcode);
```

Comment: Do ***not*** use Strings for timestamps. Create an instance of `java.sql.Timestamp` and pass it using `setTimestamp()`

Comment: Do you mind elaborating a little bit? I changed to "@QueryParam("start_date") Timestamp start_date, @QueryParam("end_date") Timestamp end_date" + "pstmt.setTimestamp(1, start_date); pstmt.setTimestamp(2, end_date);"But still doesn't work.

Comment: As of JDBC 4.2, use *java.time* objects for such work.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

For SQL using Half-Open span-of-time:
`"SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE when !< ? AND when < ? ; "`

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject(       // Use a prepared statement so you can pass smart objects rather than dumb strings.
    1 ,                              // Specify which placeholder is being fulfilled.
    LocalDate                        // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone or offset-from-UTC.
    .parse( "2014-11-20" )           // Parse an input string in standard ISO 8601 format to get a `LocalDate` object.
    .atStartOfDay()                  // Determine the first moment of the day on that date. Returns a `LocalDateTime` object representing a date with time-of-day but lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.
) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    2 , 
    LocalDate
    .parse( "2014-11-21" )
    .atStartOfDay()
) ;
```

Beware: I am guessing you are using the wrong type for your column in your database. **Moments can only be tracked with `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`**, *not* `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. Search Stack Overflow for more info.

## Not a moment

The Answer by Jens is now outmoded. Nowadays you should be using the modern *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

> “timestamp without time zone” in postgresql?

This data type on both Postgres and the SQL standard purposely lacks the context of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone. So, beware, this type cannot represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.

> I changed it to java.sql.Timestamp

Nope, wrong data type. Besides being legacy, and being terribly flawed in design, the `java.sql.Timestamp` class represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline. So this is a mismatch with your column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

## `LocalDateTime`

You should instead be using the `LocalDateTime` class. This class represents a date with a time-of-day but lacks any concept of offset or time zone.

To retrieve a value from the database.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

To send a value to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

## Start of day

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE activitydate > '2014-11-20' AND activitydate < '2014-11-21'

You have another mismatch here. You are providing a date-only value but your column holds date-with-time-of-day values.

Another problem: You are using dumb strings where you should be using smart objects. As of JDBC 4.2 we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database. Use a `PreparedStatement` with placeholders, and pass objects via the `set

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

To solve the date with time-of-day problem, we need to determine the start of the day. With `LocalDateTime`, we have no time zone anomalies to account for. So the day always starts at 00:00. Nevertheless, we should get in the habit of asking *java.time* to determine the start-of-day.

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse( "2014-11-20" ) ;
LocalDate stopDate = LocalDate.parse( "2014-11-21" ) ;

LocalDateTime start = startDate.atStartOfDay() ;
LocalDateTime stop = stopDate.atStartOfDay() ;
```

Write you SQL with placeholders.

I suggest you change your thinking to make a habit of the Half-Open approach to defining span-of-time. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So for the single entire day of the 20th, search for dates equal to or later than the 20th, and running up to, but *not* including, the 21st. As for that first part, a shorter way to say "equal to or later" is "not before", so we use `!<`.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE when !< ? AND when < ? ; " ;
```

Feed that `sql` string to your prepared statement. Then pass the two `LocalDateTime` objects for the placeholders.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , start ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , stop ) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a `java.sql.Timestamp` or a `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: `java.sql.Date` is  a bad idea, because it removes the time part (or more precisely: sets the time to `00:00:00`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in the question it looks like OP has no timepart, so `java.sql.Date` is ok for me.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating a little bit? I changed to "@QueryParam("start_date") Timestamp start_date, @QueryParam("end_date") Timestamp end_date" + "pstmt.setTimestamp(1, start_date); pstmt.setTimestamp(2, end_date);"But still doesn't work.

Comment: What means `But still doesn't work` same error message?

Comment: Just blank page. And I use "../query?start_date=2014-11-20&end_date=2014-11-21&zipcode=92093"

Comment: Can you check the result of your query? And take a look to your logfiles if there any errors.

Comment: FYI, while possibly correct some years ago, the classes shown here have now been supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes with JDBC 4.2 and later.